# ElasticSearch Bool Query or Finding Exact Values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a bit confused about [Bool Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) vs. [Finding Exact Values](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html) in elasticsearch. Specifically, I have a *title_field* and a *post_field* that I want to search on. But all of my other fields I use because I want to look up if they exist or not or how many times (like url or username which must be exact).

So I can see from the docs that I can do a [multimatch query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) on the *title_field* and *post_field*.

But what about the other fields that I want exact response from? Do I do a [boolean query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)(using must)? Or do I need to remap all of those fields as [not_analyzed](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html)? Or do I need to map them as not_anayzed **first** and **then** do a boolean query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you should map the fields you want to do exact matches on as not_analyzed, which means they are treated as a single token instead of broken into several tokens.

Then you should use a term query or filter to exactly match against the token. If you are using a filter, you can use and, or, and not filters as well (more convenient than bool).

Since mapping all fields is a bit tedious, you could instead use dynamic_mapping to map all string fields as not_analyzed and then simply add a mapping for those fields you do want analyzed:

```
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "non_analyzed_string": {
        "match": "*",
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```